# How to test `int` to `size_t` conversion without warning "comparison is always true"?

Tags: c, warnings

How to re-write code to implement the same test, but **portably** avoid the warning?

---

AFAIK, `INT_MAX` and `SIZE_MAX` are not defined to one always being >= than the other, hence the use for the following function to detect problems converting from `int` to `size_t`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

size_t int_to_size_t(int size) {
  assert(size >= 0);

  #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits"

  // Without the above pragma, below line of code may cause:
  // "warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
  // [-Wtype-limits]"
  assert((unsigned)size <= SIZE_MAX);

  #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wtype-limits"

  return (size_t) size;
}
```

Different compilers use various mechanisms to squelch warnings.  I looking for a portable solution.

The above soluton is not portable and this `gcc` method unfortunately has a side-effect: Warning `-Wtype-limits`, which may or may not have been enabled is now enabled after this code.  Do not know how to restore `-Wtype-limits` setting.

Ref:
[Portability of #warning preprocessor directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171435/portability-of-warning-preprocessor-directive)
[Suppress comparison always true warning for Macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542857/suppress-comparison-always-true-warning-for-macros)

Comment: Note: Using 4.8.2 gcc and "gcc -std=c99 -O1 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion".  Would like it to work on many compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could replace this:

```
assert((unsigned)size <= SIZE_MAX);
```

by:

```
#if INT_MAX > SIZE_MAX
assert((unsigned)size <= SIZE_MAX);
#endif
```

If the `#if` condition is false, the `assert` condition is always true and the `assert` is unnecessary. The `(unsigned)` cast is (probably) necessary to avoid a warning about a comparison between signed and unsigned operands.

Warning: I have not tested this. (To fully test it, I'd need access to a system with `int` wider than `size_t`, and I've never seen such a system.)

Comment: BTW: Love the "Warning: ..." in an answer about getting rid of warnings. :-)

Comment: I think you got both comparisons a bit wrong, please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Keith states correctly, you'd only have to worry when the value of `INT_MAX` is greater than the one for `SIZE_MAX`. If you want to compare these values in the preprocessor (and you should) you can't cast to make `INT_MAX` an unsigned type. (The preprocessor doesn't know about casts.)

Therefore you have to add `0U` to the value so both expression become `uintmax_t`. (For the preprocessor integer constants are `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t`).

```
#if (INT_MAX+0U) > SIZE_MAX
assert(size <= (int)SIZE_MAX);
#endif
```

Then inside this `#if` you know that `SIZE_MAX` is less that `INT_MAX` so you may cast it down to `int` without changing the value.

Comment: I don't think the `+0U` is necessary. As far as the preprocessor is concerned, `INT_MAX` is of type `intmax_t`, and `SIZE_MAX` is of type `uintmax_t`. The `<` operator converts the `intmax_t` operand to `uintmax_t` and then compares the two operands.

Comment: @KeithThompson, none of the casts is "necessary". There are good rules on how signed types are converted to unsigned ones, there is no real problem, here. The problem are compilers that are overprotective, and the pseudo-cast in the preprocessor part could avoid that.

Comment: Ok, the cast may avoid a warning -- but experiments shows that gcc, at least doesn't warn about signed vs. unsigned comparisons in preprocessor expressions. Perhaps other compilers are pickier.